# Elasticsearch [filtered] query does not support [suggest]

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, geo

I want to allow our users to search for objects by text and geo location. When searching by text though I would like it suggest terms to as you would with a normal query and a completion suggestor. When I try to add the suggestor to my filtered query I get an error. Any suggestions?

My mapping:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/objects/object/_mapping -d '{
  "object": {
    "properties": {
      "objectDescription": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "suggest": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "payloads": true
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/objects/object/_mapping -d '{
    "object":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}}
}'
```

My search:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "objectDescription": {
            "value": "burger"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "15mi",
              "location": {
                "lat": 33.4255104,
                "lon": -111.94000540000002
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "administrative_area_level_1": "AZ"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "addressType": "administrative_area_level_1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I add the suggest at the same level as the query as you would without a filter it ignores my filter. It will find the object when searched that is no where near the lat lng.

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "query":{
                "fuzzy":{
                    "objectDescription":{"value":"bears"}
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "bool":{
                    "should":[
                        {
                            "geo_distance":{
                                "distance":"15mi",
                                "location":{
                                    "lat":43.6187102,
                                    "lon":-116.21460680000001
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool":{
                                "must":[
                                    {
                                        "term":{"administrative_area_level_1":"ID"}
                                },{
                                        "term":{"addressType":"administrative_area_level_1"}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "suggest":{
        "object-suggest":{
            "text":"bears",
            "completion":{
                "field":"suggest",
                "fuzzy":{"fuzziness":2}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I place the suggest portion of the body in place of the query I get this error.

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "suggest":{
                "object-suggest":{
                    "text":"bears",
                    "completion":{
                        "field":"suggest",
                        "fuzzy":{"fuzziness":2}
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "bool":{
                    "should":[
                        {
                            "geo_distance":{
                                "distance":"15mi",
                                "location":{
                                    "lat":43.6187102,
                                    "lon":-116.21460680000001
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool":{
                                "must":[
                                    {
                                        "term":{"administrative_area_level_1":"ID"}
                                },{
                                        "term":{"addressType":"administrative_area_level_1"}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is I haven't found an example on elastic.co or on stackoverflow that has this combination of geolocation searching with a completion suggestor.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that yields the error, as there's no suggest in it?

Comment: Hi Val! Sorry for not including the actual body that was giving the error and thank you for cleaning up my code snippets. I included the problem filter query with the suggest. My goal is to have search text with a suggestor using geolocation filter. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. The `suggest` block goes at the top-level on its own:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "15mi",
                "location": {
                  "lat": 43.6187102,
                  "lon": -116.21460680000001
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "administrative_area_level_1": "ID"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "addressType": "administrative_area_level_1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "object-suggest": {
      "text": "bears",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "fuzzy": {
          "fuzziness": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For your precise use case, I think you should use the [context suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html#suggester-context-geo) with a geo-location context, instead of a simple completion suggester. That's most certainly what you need in order to achieve what you expect.

Comment: So when I add the suggest at the top-level it seems to ignore my geo_distance filter. The bears object has a lat lng of Tempe, AZ. When I search within 15mi of Tempe, AZ the object is returned. When I search within 15mi of Boise, ID the same object is still returned. When I don't use suggest and only the geo_distance filter it works as expected. The object is returned for the Tempe lat lng and not the Boise lat lng.

Comment: If you absolutely need the geo_distance filter why do you add it to the `bool/should`? It should be in the `bool/must`, right?

Comment: I would like to return objects for the desired lat lng as well as the "parent" of that lat lng in this case being the state. So give me all the objects within 15mi of this lat lng and any results that are just in that state and don't have a specific location in the state. That is why it is in should.

Comment: Hmm, you might need to use a [context suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html#suggester-context-geo) (with geo-location context) instead of a simple completion suggester.

Comment: Okay interesting. I came across this before but ignored it but looking at it again I think you are right. I think the only way to achieve what I want is to do this. Thanks for taking the time to take a look! I appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem, hope it helps.

Comment: While I have your attention and you know what I am trying to do any idea why the bool -> must with the adminstrative_area_level_1 and addressType are not working? When I have just the addressType equal to administrative_area_level_1 it pulls objects based on the geo_distance filter or administrative_area_level_1 objects. As soon as I try to say which administrative_area_level_1 it is it won't pull administrative_area_level_1 objects anymore. Even with it by itself not defining the addressType it wont pull administrative_area_level_1.

Comment: When I get enough rep I will come back and give you an up vote! Thanks again!

Comment: I think it might be because `administrative_area_level_1` is an analyzed field. Try in lowercase with `"administrative_area_level_1": "id"` instead. The correct way would be to make `administrative_area_level_1` a `not_analyzed` field, though.

Comment: Yep! That was it! Good call mate :) The lowercase worked. So I need to make it a not_analyzed field. Thank you again. I will go forward with the context suggester and report back. If it works you should make that the answer and I can check it off (it will show when I have the rep I think).